# Drag Manager - how to access the target of dragging event in my dragDropHandler?

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I'm making a Matching Game where I have some images on my left and I can drag them onto images on my right and if they are matching, they should both disappear from the stage.

MXML code:

```
<mx:VBox>
<mx:Repeater id="rp" dataProvider="{urlAC}">
<mx:Image width="150" height="150" source="{rp.currentItem}"                                  
mouseMove="initiateDrag(event,event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem())"/>
</mx:Repeater>
</mx:VBox>
<mx:VBox>
<mx:Repeater id="rp1" dataProvider="{matchAC}">
<mx:Image width="150" height="150" source="{rp1.currentItem}"                              
dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event, event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem())"                            
dragDrop="dragDropHandler(event)"/>
</mx:Repeater>
</mx:VBox>
```

Event handlers:

```
        private function initiateDrag(event:MouseEvent,path:String):void
        {
            findMatch(path);

            var dragInitiator:Image = Image(event.currentTarget);
            var datasource:DragSource = new DragSource();
            datasource.addData(matchTarget, "match");  

            DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, datasource, event);
        }

        private function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent, pathMatch:String):void 
        {
            var dropTarget:Image =event.currentTarget as Image;

            if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("match") && event.dragSource.dataForFormat("match")==pathMatch)
            {
                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(dropTarget);
            }
        }

        private function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void 
        {
            event.currentTarget.source="";
        }
```

findMatch() is a function that finds in my XML file the path of the file that matches the file that is being dragged. Having that path, I send it to dragEnterHandler where it compares it with the path of the dropTarget file and if they are the same, it accepts it. Then in dragDropHandler, I'm changing the source path of my second image to "", so that it disappears from the stage. How can I access the first file (the one that was being dragged), so that I can change its path to "", to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that you can get the instance of the image object that initiated the drag from the dragInitiator property of the DragEvent.

However, if that, for whatever reason, does not work, you can always add your image control as data on the dataSource.